# What does "breakdown" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a passage from an [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizophrenia) article on Schizophrenia:

> Schizophrenia is a mental disorder characterized by a *breakdown* of thought processes and by a deficit of typical emotional responses.

What does *breakdown* here mean? Does it mean to make incomplete, like they are unable to complete the thought process thus it *breaks* it?

Comment: I think this is General Reference. [Breakdown](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/breakdown) *- a failure of a relationship or system*. That's to say, the primary sense here is of *broken = non-functional, damaged*, not *broken = interrupted, incomplete*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something breaks down, it falls apart or stops working.  In this case, schizophrenics have a thought process that doesn't work.  The wikipedia entry that you have quoted (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizophrenia) continues "Common symptoms are delusions and disorganized thinking including auditory hallucinations, paranoia, bizarre delusions, disorganized speech..." These symptoms are examples of the breakdown mentioned.

From http://www.thefreedictionary.com/breakdown:

```
1.
    a. The act or process of failing to function or continue.
    b. The condition resulting from this: a breakdown in communication.
2. Electricity The abrupt failure of an insulator or insulating medium to restrict the flow of current.
3. A typically sudden collapse in physical or mental health.
4. An analysis, an outline, or a summary consisting of itemized data or essentials.
5. Disintegration or decomposition into parts or elements.
6. A noisy, energetic American country dance.
```

Your quote is an example of definition 3.